# What is a simple QFT calculation that could show that some theory of Quantum Gravity might be correct?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, unified-theories

Imagine that we could do QFT calculations with a Hamiltonian that takes GR into account.

What is a relatively simple calculation that could show that this theory is more accurate than a "normal" QFT?

I'm thinking something along the lines of:

The scattering process of an electron and a positron should, with respect to the "normal QFT", show a slightly greater probability of their final momenta causing the particles to move closer together.

This would mean greater attraction.

Should this be a feature of such a theory?

Are there simpler calculations than the one described above?

Comment: About the only "simple" thing a quantum theory of gravity might provide is an explanation of what dark matter and dark energy are.